# Detect if Chrome NaCl is available

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

Is there a way to detect if NaCl is available on the current browser?

It seems that checking for `chrome.app.isInstalled` turns into false positive on some non-Chrome browsers

Answer (score 5):

You can check if the browser handles the NaCl mime type. E.g.:

```
navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-nacl'] !== undefined.
```

Similarly, for PNaCl, you can check for `'application/x-pnacl'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for Chrome and a particular version of Chrome like this:

```
var have_nacl = false;
var have_pnacl = false;

var index = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome');
if (index != -1) {
  var version = parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(index + 7));

  if (31 <= version) have_pnacl = true;
  if (14 <= version) have_nacl = true;
}
```

However, this does not tell the full story.  Versions 31+ have PNaCl and it's enabled by default.  NaCl is only enabled by default for apps in the Chrome store so you would still need to test if NaCl is enabled.  One way to do this is to set a watchdog timer then try to load an NaCl module and capture the *load* event.  In the *load* event clear the watchdog timer.  For example:

```
var watchdog;
var watchdog_time;

function watchdog_timeout() {
  alert('NaCl module failed to load');
}

function watchdog_clear() {
  clearTimeout(watchdog);
}

function watchdog_set(time) {
  watchdog_time = time;
  watchdog = setTimeout(watchdog_timeout, time);
}

watchdog_set(5000); // Timeout in 5 sec

var module = document.getElementById('module'); // Use your module's ID
module.addEventListener('load', function () {
  watchdog_clear();
  alert('NaCl module loaded');
}, true);

// Inject the module, where module.nmf is your NMF file.
module.innerHTML = '<embed src="module.nmf" type="application/x-nacl"/>';
```

This requires that you have something like the following somewhere in your HTML:

```
<div id="module"></div>
```

If your module takes awhile to download you might also want to capture the *loadstart* and *progress* events and extend the watchdog time.

```
function watchdog_extend() {
  watchdog_clear();
  watchdog_set(watchdog_time);
}

module.addEventListener('loadstart', watchdog_extend, true);
module.addEventListener('progress', watchdog_extend, true);
```